# Получение позиции курсора из richTextBox C#

Tags: c#

Такая проблема, нужно получить позицию курсора в richTextBox, чтобы вывести в statusStrip.Позицию курсора можно получить с помощью selected, проблема в том, что не понимаю как узнать на какой он строке и на каком символе в строке. Помогите или подскажите алгоритм. На скрине показал, куда хочу вывести номер строки и символа.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для примера. Вот строка из VSC.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox

Comment: Point pos = new Point((Cursor.Position.X - this.Location.X - panel1.Location.X - panel5.Location.X), (Cursor.Position.Y - this.Location.Y - panel1.Location.Y - panel5.Location.Y)); Заменяете название элементов и всё.